# Ropsten accounts getting emptied by unauthorized transactions

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

we're currently in the middle of developing a DAP (using Ropsten testnet) which for the time being uses 3 different accounts for various aspects of its functionality. Development and testing was going great for the last couple of month until suddenly since earlier today the ether in each account was reduced to 0.

Thinking it was a kind of Ropsten bug (or feature, being a testnet), tried to use faucets to add some ether in each account to continue the development but again the ether was reduced to 0 after a few minutes. Upon further investigation, through etherscan, we found out that all of our accounts where "authorizing" a constant stream of transactions towards a specific account i.e. 0xD9eE4D08a86b430544254Ff95e32aa6fcc1d3163.

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xd9ee4d08a86b430544254ff95e32aa6fcc1d3163

We're thinking this could be some sort of Ropsten's feature to demotivate users using it for production purposes, which I guess could make sense somehow. Or maybe our accounts got hacked? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're likely using the [personal API](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html) and unlocking your accounts. There are a multitude of bots in existence which repetitively scan and attempt to find open Ethereum RPC endpoints (most commonly found by scanning port 8545) which have the personal API exposed.

You should highly consider either or both of the following:

1. Not keeping keys stored on your node(s) and pre-signing transactions in code or via an external wallet such as MetaMask.
2. Not exposing your RPC endpoint to the internet and locking it down to specific clients such as your DApp.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, sounds very much like that is the issue. Will try to implement your suggested solutions.